# Fourier transform example

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-transform, transformation, cauchy-problem

How can I find the fourier transform of the function

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |x| < 1/2 \\ 1/2 & |x| = 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

and a second question of the integrate circle of Cauchy theorem,

$$
\oint \frac{z+2}{z^2 + 1} \ \mathrm{d}z \quad \quad |z| = 2$$

I will be grateful for solution or any example that I can use to calculate it.

Comment: Hi gws. We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, but if you could confirm that I've edited it correctly, that would be great. In particular it's still somewhat unclear why you included the $\oint \frac{z+2}{z^2 + 1}\ \mathrm{d}z$...

Comment: Hello. Yes, the new format is right. I am so sorry, I am new in this webpage. How do you applied this correct format? Did you use some another math webpage? Best, G

Comment: but there is a little changing, the integrate of the Cauchy theorem would be a second question and it is not part of the first.

Comment: As the two questions are totally unrelated, you should ask them in different posts. Please edit the post and ask the contour integral in the different post.

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the Fourier transform, define a $\hat f(\xi)$ as the Fourier transform of $f(x)$ such that

$$\hat f(\xi ) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{-2\pi i x\xi}\, \mathrm dx $$
Using this definition, in our case
$$\hat f(\xi) = \int\limits_{-1/2}^{1/2} e^{-2\pi i x\xi} \,\mathrm dx $$
Because the other integrals will be $0$. Evaluating this integral using Euler's formula gives us $\hat f(\xi ) = \frac{\sin(\pi \xi)}{\pi\xi} $.

Now the contour integral. We notice that the integrand has simple poles inside the contour at $z=i,-i$. The residues at these points are $\frac{i+2}{2i}$ and $\frac{i-2}{2i}$ respectively. Finally using the Cauchy residue theorem, we conclude that
$$\int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{z+2}{z^2+1}\,\mathrm dz =2\pi i$$

Comment: Laxmi Narayan Bhandari, in this case, will be zero the integral applying the limit option of 1/2, ||=1/2 over the −2 ? I understood in your answer that you applied the  1, ||<1/2 limit, once that the value of 1*−2 = −2

Comment: If you are talking about the case $|x|=1/2\implies f(x) = 1/2$, then yes. As we know, integrals at a single point vanish, so our Fourier series will also vanish. This statement is a bit non-rigorous, and I don't know how to explain it rigourously using real analysis. @gwsmelo